# Laravel Socialite - get date of birth and email while loging in with facebook

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-socialite

This is in my routes

```
Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Front@redirectToProvider');
```

Front.php

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
  return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}
```

But in permission window i don't see permission for phone number . how to add that perission?

[image]

[image]

Laravel Framework version 5.2.45

**Update**: It seems i can't get the phone number but it seems i can get date of birth .My idea was that if i know how to get phone then i can use the same code to get other fields too like email and date of birth . What do i need to add and where to get these fields?

Comment: Didn't know that I never worked much on fb integration , btw any way to get other fields like date of birth etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the phone number of a Facebook User. There is not even a field for it in the user table: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

About birthday and other fields, see this thread: [How to get birthday gender and religion information using laravel socialite implementing facebook Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843915/how-to-get-birthday-gender-and-religion-information-using-laravel-socialite-impl)

Comment: Didn't know that I never worked much on fb integration , btw any way to get other fields like date of birth etc?

Comment: which fields you can get is explained in the link in my answer. of course you need additional permission for many fields. user_birthday for the birthday, for example. you are already asking for the email permission, so you should know how to ask for more.

Comment: Ohh got it thanx