# Input Facebook Data (Gender, Birthdate, Address and Bio) into database with Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-socialite

I have created a complete code which allows Facebook Login by getting Name, Email and Avatar of the user in the database by using Laravel Socialite.

I did it by writing this:

```
$user = User::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                'avatar' => $providerUser->getAvatar(),
                'password' => md5(rand(1,10000)),
            ]);
```

But for putting Gender, BirthDate and Address in the database, I tried this.

```
$user = User::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                'avatar' => $providerUser->getAvatar(),
                'gender' => $providerUser->getGender(),
                'bio' => $providerUser->getBio(),
                'password' => md5(rand(1,10000)),
            ]);
```

But, there are no functions such as `getGender()` or `getBio()`. Do you know what they are?

I have also asked necessary permissions to Facebook Driver in `SocialController.php`

```
public function redirect()
  {
      return Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday'
        ])->scopes([
            'email', 'user_birthday'
        ])->redirect();
  }
```

All necessary stuffs like Database Tables, Migrations, Models and a working project without Gender and Bio is ready. But I need to add more info in database. How can I do so?

I search such questions already on StackOverflow but didn't find a satisfying answer. I hope someone answers this.

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: There isn’t a specific getter for every single possible field ... but you don’t need one in the first place. Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile for an easy example how this can be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default socialite provider for Facebook does not have the method to get gender & bio.

***For more info, You can check the available methods here:***

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/src/Contracts/User.php
https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/src/AbstractUser.php

***This StackOverflow might help you:***

[How to get birthday gender and religion information using laravel socialite implementing facebook Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843915/how-to-get-birthday-gender-and-religion-information-using-laravel-socialite-impl/37846413)

Apart from getting the scope in redirect you also need to pass them in call back

```
 public function handleFacebookCallback()
{
    $facebook_user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday'
    ])->user();
}
```

***Check available helper methods***

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/src/AbstractUser.php

- offsetExists('gender')
- offsetGet('gender')

These methods can help get extra info from users array