# Laravel Socialite Facebook not returning gender

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Wondering if you can help me. Im using laravel socialite for login purposes. My problem is that i cant seem to get the users gender in my production env conde below:

```
 $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
            'first_name', 'last_name','gender', 'email', 
        ])->user();
```

The only difference in the two environments is that my prod env is using facebooks api v3.1 but surely it should still be returning gender?

Comment: what has the changeset said about differences of api versions, have you looked?

Comment: Have you actually checked the API documents for 3.1 to see if gender is an allowed field? Or are you just assuming it is?

Comment: @Joe https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/user gender is still a core value.

Comment: So what happens when you change your dev to use the same api version?

Comment: hope this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843915/how-to-get-birthday-gender-and-religion-information-using-laravel-socialite-impl

Comment: @Joe if i update the the dev to use the v3.1 of the api it then breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `user_gender` at the scopes of Socialite request.

Like this for redirect endpoint:

```
Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields(['name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday', 'likes', 'location'])->scopes(['user_gender', 'user_likes', 'email', 'user_birthday'])->redirect();
```

Like this for callback endpoint:

```
Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields(['name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday', 'likes', 'location'])->user()
```

Then returns all information mentioned at fields. Like name, email, gender, birthday, all page likes and current city.